# Right-clicking in the terminal opens new window... stop this?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal, gnome

When in a terminal window, right-clicking often opens a new terminal rather than displaying the menu. (I'm not sure if this is because of where I click, or if I'm hitting another button, or something else -- but it happens often, maybe 5 times a day.)

Is there a way to disable this behavior?

(I'm not sure what causes this, exactly... Metacity? GNOME?  I don't think it's the shell itself.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In gnome-terminal, if you right-click and hold, you'll see a context menu. The first item is Open Terminal. It is likely that you're moving the mouse a little and releasing the button thus selecting that option.

**Edit:**

You can edit the file at `/usr/share/gnome-terminal/terminal.xml` and rearrange the order of the items in the `<popup name="Popup" action="Popup">` section. You could put Copy and Paste at the top swapping positions with Open Window and Open Tab.

Comment: That is almost surely it.  Is there a way to modify the menu?

Comment: @Charles: See my edit.

Comment: Fantastic!  This does exactly what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't sound quite right for behavior. If you create a "blank" account (new user) and log in, does the same behavior persist? Sounds like a preference was changed.

Comment: Yes, same behavior.  I'm not sure exactly what I'm doing that triggers it (it's always on a right-click, but by no means on all right-clicks).  It'[s really annoying...

Comment: Is there a setting that changed your right-click behavior preference for the mouse in the preferences/settings?

Comment: I don't know of any such settings.  The mouse is pretty standard, nothing fancy -- no custom drivers.

Comment: You're running latest Ubuntu with standard interface?